# Force one div to change size of other div inside the same parent, so the first one can be seen

Tags: html, css

I have a div with two contents: an image (on top) and text (on bottom).

Height of image plus height of the text is bigger than the height of the parent.
I want an image to shrink, so the whole text will be visible.

So - now it looks like this:
[image]

And I want it to look like this:
[image]

How to achieve this?

I tried it with `display: flex` and `flex-shrink` or `flex-grow`, but it's not working.

Solution with `flex` will be much appreciated :)

Here's a codepen with an example:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zQXyLb

And here's code used:

```html
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body style="background: yellow;">
    
        <div style="
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            background: #ddd;
            overflow: hidden;
    
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        ">
            <div>
              <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/198/skull_1f480.png">
            </div>
              <div>
                <div>Here i have some text</div>
                <div>which is multiline</div>
                <div>and it should make</div>
                <div>the skull smaller</div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `img` tag try `div` with `background-image`.

`flex:` is short form of: `flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis`.

`0 0 auto` means that element will take just as much space as needed.

`1 1 auto` means that element will take all available space — so image takes box size minus text size. And text is always visible.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ddd;
}

.image {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: url(https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/198/skull_1f480.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.text {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <div>Here I have some text</div>
    <div>which is multiline</div>
    <div>and it should make</div>
    <div>the skull smaller</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <div>Here I have small text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you pls add a word of explanation re the `flex: 1 1 auto` and `flex: 0 0 auto` commands in your answer?

Comment: @gibberish `flex` is short of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis`. `0 0 auto` means that element will take just as much space as needed. `1 1 auto` means that element will take all available space — so image takes box size minus text size. And text is always visible.

Answer (score 2):

You can also keep image in the HTMl if you inbricate flex boxes to allow img container to shrink and img understand `max-height:100%;`

```css
body {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
}

[class],
[class]>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
}

[class]>div[id] {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class style="
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            background: #ddd;
        ">
  <div>
    <img src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/198/skull_1f480.png">
  </div>
  <div id>
    <div>Here i have some text</div>
    <div>which is multiline</div>
    <div>and it should make</div>
    <div>the skull smaller</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This solution is accualy better for me. But I don't really get why it works. It seems like `overflow: hidden` on the `div` which is a parent of `img` does the job, but i have no idea why oO

Comment: @pbialy overflow:hidden gives a maximum size to the box that the flex model can use. the children have a value to use for height or max-height.

Comment: @gibberish sublevels are inbricated in upperlevels.  a flex parent can have a flex child. the child will be a flex child and also a flex parent.  [class] selects every element that has a class attribute. [id] = id attribute and so on.

Comment: Thanks @G-Cyr - I understand that imbrication refers to overlapping in a regular pattern (as in roof tiles and fish scales), but what does it mean when you say `sublevels are inbricated in upperlevels` ?

Comment: @gibberish okay : russian dolls are inbricated , ... am i about to learn something about english ;)

Comment: Ahhhh - that helps. Russian dolls are the perfect example - many thanks. Now I fully understand your answer. I am quite knowledgeable about English but didn't know that word -- and a google search didn't suggest the Russian dolls motif. *If only we could tweak Google search results...*

Answer (score -1):

1. Resize the image using css.

```
img{
  max-width:50px;
}
```

The above code should make the image flexible and allow it to be smaller.

2. Also you can put variable height to the parent div, i.e.

```
<div style="
           width: 150px;
           max-height: 250px;  //added this part
           background: #ddd;
           overflow: hidden;

           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
       ">
```

But this way the image will stay large but the parent's height will increase. Allowing the text to appear in the enlarged div.

Comment: This is totally not what I wanted.  
It will work for a single img and single text. If they change - it will break.